# Apache Poi Date value

Tags: java, date, datetime, apache-poi

i try to save type date at my database but i got this error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a NUMERIC value from a
> STRING cell

this is my code

```
rfx.setRv_rc_date(row.getCell(67).getDateCellValue());
```

please what i should to do to get this value format date !

Comment: The error is pretty clear. The cell `row.getCell(67)` does not contain a date but a string. So first question would be: Why is that? Look in your `Excel` file to get why that is. What row is `row`? And what is the exact content of column `BP` in that row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get a Date type value from a String type cell, there are 2 ways you can do:

1. change the type of the cell in your excel file.
2. get a String value from the cell in your codes, and then manually format it from String to Date by using SimpleDataFormat or other date formatter.

Comment: Your second option is not possible without knowing further context. For example if the cell contains the text "03/03/2020", what date format will this be? Will it be DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY? Same but more worse with "3/3/3". Will this be D/M/Y or M/D/Y or Y/M/D? And what about "03.03.2020"? Will this even be a date? For me, yes. It is March, 3, 2020 in German date format DD.MM.YYYY.

Comment: @AxelRichter Yes, the second option is only working in the condition that you have already known the format of that date String